# Sign a XML file with .pfx certificate using Java

Tags: java, xml, security, certificate, digital-signature

I need to sign a XML file using a certificate .p12 using Java. I have tried to see any examples with different methods but doesnt work.
I saw Apache-Santuario but it is not any information about how to do it.
There is any lib or something to do this or address me in the right direction to do

Thks In Advance

Comment: What kind of signature do you need?